# CakePHP 3 - Session configuration for logging in via a subdomain

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

I'm building an application on a subdomain using CakePHP 3.

Users login to `https://example.com/` which is written in vanilla PHP (5.x)

The Cake app resides on `https://app.example.com/`. I have added the following to `config/app.php`. The intention of this is that the Cake app can read the session variables from the login domain (`https://example.com`).

```
'Session' => [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID',
    'timeout' => '0',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_domain' => '.example.com',
        'session.cookie_httponly' => 'on'
    ]
]
```

All of this works fine. I can print out session variables which are set by `https://example.com` on `https://app.example.com`.

However, I'm not convinced Cake is actually treating the configuration correctly (or even using it at all)...

I was curious as to how `session.cookie_domain` works so started changing the value. In the end I changed it to something nonsensical such as

```
'session.cookie_domain' => 'ksjdhshfksdf'
```

and it all still worked as before.

The only way in which I can "break" it is to set `'cookie' => 'PHPSESSID'` to `'cookie' => 'CAKEPHP'`, which renders the session unreadable (as it's going back to Cake's own session handler rather than the "vanilla" PHP one?)

Please can someone explain this, or if it's set up incorrectly for my needs?

Incidentally the server's `php.ini` has been configured to include `session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"`. I'm unclear if this may be where the problem lies - perhaps because Cake is using `php.ini` for the session settings, the `ini` part of the array is not actually meaningful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `session.cookie_domain` option only affects *writing* session cookies, not reading them. It's the user agent that decides whether to send a cookie alongside the request depending on the domain settings that the server responded with when responding with the cookie.

When a cookie is being sent by a user agent, there will be no domain config value, only the cookie name and its value, so PHP couldn't make use of the domain setting even if it wanted to, it simply has no clue where a cookie originally stems from.

On the server side, sessions are always initialized by PHP itself, all CakePHP can do is call `session_start()`, and the only thing that matters to PHP is the cookie name and its value. If the cookie name matches the configured session cookie name, then its value will be used to identify a possible session (that is where a custom session handler can hook in), and that's all there is to it on the server side with regards to picking up sessions.

What you could break with a wrong `cookie_domain` setting, is session renewal, as it will destory the session store, and write a cookie with a domain value that will cause the user agent to not send it on subsequent requests.

Comment: The documentation https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration isn't clear on this. Specifically the bit which says "if you want your session to persist across all subdomains". If it's using the settings in php.ini anyway, then surely this would happen anyway?

Comment: @Andy PHP will use whatever is currently configured, being it hardcoded in the `php.ini`, or set/overwritten at runtime (which is what CakePHP will do). The example is just an example to illustrate the usage of the `ini` option. I'd say that the underlying session and cookie mechanisms are PHP/HTTP principles that don't neccesarily need to be elaborated in the CakePHP docs. But that's just my personal opinion, please feel free to open an issue or push a PR with changes for the docs if you think there's need for clarification, improvements are always welcome! **https://github.com/cakephp/docs**